# How do I run 2 versions of Xcode (the .app version)?

Tags: xcode

Are there any issues to installing two versions of Xcode since they have moved to the .app version?

Back in the day would set up separate directory trees to keep my Xcode worlds from colliding. Is that nolonger needed?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 2):

No issues. I do it every time there are beta versions.
You just need to **rename the app** if they are in the same directory.

As always, use `xcode-select` to set the default one.